# How to center dynamic element that keeps changing width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I'm making a rotating title that displays different span elements on an interval. I'm having trouble horizontally centering the #rotatingWords in its parent element, as all the spans are different widths. I've always used transform: translate for things like this but the way I have my animation set up is making the words slowly drift from their original spot to where they are being translated. Is there another way to perfectly center all of the different widths, or is there a way to make transform: translate not show the drift?

here is my html

```
<div id="bigDiv">
    <div id="rotatingContainer">
       <p id="your">Your</p>
          <div id="rotatingWords">
            <span className="words">Roofing</span>
            <span className="words">Siding</span>
            <span className="words">Windows</span>
            <span className="words">Gutters</span>
          </div>
       <p id="contractor">Contractor!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my css

```
#bigDiv {
  position: relative;
}

#rotatingContainer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 85%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
p {
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Copperplate, Copperplate Gothic Medium, fantasy;
  color: white;
}

#rotatingWords {
  color: green;
  font-size: 3vw;
  font-family: Copperplate, Copperplate Gothic Medium, fantasy;
  width: max-content;
}

#rotatingWords span {
  animation: rotateWordsFirst 12s linear infinite 0s;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: -15% 0 0 18%;
}

#rotatingWords span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: #6b889d;
}
#rotatingWords span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  color: #6b739d;
}
#rotatingWords span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
  color: #7a6b9d;
}

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    height: 0px;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 90px;
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 90px;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 90px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  #your{
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-top: 4px;
  }
}
```

So far I've tried margin: auto and transform: translate.